# Magento 2.4.6 building custom admin grid filter issue

Tags: grid, uicomponent, filter, magento2.4.6

I built my own custom admin grid. It renders the data correctly, however when I tried to filter on an input, I am receiving the following error from the ajax request:

```
Status code 500
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Magento\Sales\Plugin\Model\ResourceModel\Order\OrderGridCollectionFilter::aroundAddFieldToFilter(): 
Argument #1 ($subject) must be of type Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult, Vendor\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\MoodleLogs\Grid\Collection\Interceptor given, 
called in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php on line 135 and defined in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-sales/Plugin/Model/ResourceModel/Order/OrderGridCollectionFilter.php:41
```

Interesting part is that I don't have any dependencies from the **Magento Sales** module.
This is my di.xml part:

```
<virtualType name="Vendor\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\MoodleLogs\Grid\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">moodle_logs</argument>
        <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Vendor\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\MoodleLogs</argument>
        <argument name="eventPrefix" xsi:type="string">vendor_modulename_logs_grid_collection</argument>
        <argument name="eventObject" xsi:type="string">vendor_logs_grid_collection</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="vendor_modulename_moodle_logs_grid_data" xsi:type="string">Vendor\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\MoodleLogs\Grid\Collection</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

and this is part of my UI component:

```
<dataSource name="bookingsystem_bookings_list_data_source">
    <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
        <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider</argument>
        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">vendor_modulename_moodle_logs_grid_data</argument>
        <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">entity_id</argument>
        <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </argument>
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</dataSource>

<listingToolbar name="listing_top">
    <settings>
        <sticky>true</sticky>
    </settings>
    <columnsControls name="columns_controls"/>
    <paging name="listing_paging"/>
    <filters name="listing_filters">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="templates" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filters" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="select" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select</item>
                            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
            <item name="observers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="column" xsi:type="string">column</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </filters>
</listingToolbar>
```

Not sure why Ii am getting that error from the magento/module-sales plugin . Any idea ?

If I disable the core plugin, it works:

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
    <plugin name="orderGridCollectionFilterPlugin" type="Magento\Sales\Plugin\Model\ResourceModel\Order\OrderGridCollectionFilter"/>
</type>
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you find any solutions for it?

Comment: Facing the same issue did you have solutions for it? Kindly share it as answer if you found any it would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

when your delete controller call then add this code

```
 use Vendore\Module\Model\ResourceModel\YourModelName\CollectionFactory;
 use Vendore\Module\Model\YourModelFactory;



public function execute()
{
    $customData = $this->collectionFactory->create();

    foreach ($customData as $value) {
        $templateId[] = $value['id'];
    }
    $parameterData = $this->getRequest()->getParams('id');
    $selectedAppsid = $this->getRequest()->getParams('id');

    if (array_key_exists("selected", $parameterData)) {
        $selectedAppsid = $parameterData['selected'];
    }
    if (array_key_exists("excluded", $parameterData)) {
        if ($parameterData['excluded'] == 'false') {
            $selectedAppsid = $templateId;
        } else {
            $selectedAppsid = array_diff($templateId, $parameterData['excluded']);
        }
    }
    $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addFieldToFilter('id', ['in' => $selectedAppsid]);
    $delete = 0;
    $model = [];
    foreach ($collection as $item) {
        $this->deleteByIds($item->getId());
        $delete++;
    }
    $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('A total of %1 Records have been deleted.', $delete));
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
    return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/notification');
}

public function deleteByIds($id)
{
    $item = $this->YourModelFactory->create()->load($id);
    $item->delete();
}
```